# ruby: instance_eval a file while maintaining file:line in stacktrace?

Tags: ruby

If I do

```
def eval_file(file)
  instance_eval read(file)
end
```

Then once something happens in one of the methods / blocks inside the file all I see is something like `(eval):20 in 'eval_file`'. When I use eval_file with many files it is hard to tell from which one the exception came (the exception happens after the eval, when using a method)

Is there some way for me to see the actual file and line number?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you can see from [the documentation](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/BasicObject:instance_eval), `BasicObject#instance_eval` (and in fact all the other `*_eval`s as well) will simply report whatever file name and line number you tell it to:

> ## Method: BasicObject#instance_eval
>
> - (`Object`) `instance_eval(string[, filename [, lineno]])`
>
> Evaluates a string containing Ruby source code, or the given block, within the context of the receiver (*obj*). In order to set the context, the variable `self` is set to *obj* while the code is executing, giving the code access to *obj*’s instance variables. In the version of `instance_eval` that takes a `String`, **the optional second and third parameters supply a filename and starting line number that are used when reporting compilation errors**.
>
> […]
>
> ### Overloads:
>
> - (`Object`) `instance_eval(string[, filename [, lineno]])`

[Emphasis mine.]

In general, if you use the `String` overload of the `*_eval` methods, you should make sure that you get [sensible location information by passing file name and line number](http://OlaBini.Com/blog/2008/01/ruby-antipattern-using-eval-without-positioning-information/) [[alternative link](http://Ola-Bini.BlogSpot.Com/2008/01/ruby-antipattern-using-eval-without.html)].

In your particular case, you would omit the line number, since you want Ruby to simply use the line number(s) of the file, but you need to pass the file name:

```
def eval_file(file)
  instance_eval read(file), file
end
```